# Looping through a menu items in C#

Tags: loops

I am trying to make a menu where I can add some video game information until I decide to quit the program. So far, I have this:

```
    do
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Select the number of your choice: ");
        Console.WriteLine("1: Add a game");
        Console.WriteLine("2: Remove a game");
        Console.WriteLine("3: List games");
        Console.WriteLine("4: Save games");
        Console.WriteLine("5: Read games from file");
        Console.WriteLine("6: Quit");
        Console.Write("Enter the number of your choice: ");
        userChoice = Console.ReadLine();
    } while (!Int32.TryParse(userChoice, out num)); //checks to see if the input is a number
    if (userChoice == "6")
    {
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }
```

The code stops after it displays the choice. I'm trying to display the menu again after it displays the choice so that the user can pick another number. Ultimately, I would want it to look something like this:

Until the user inputs a 6 and quits the program. What edits can I do in order to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To continue looping, all of your logic will have to go *inside* the loop!

```
    int num;
    string userChoice;

    do
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Select the number of your choice: ");
        Console.WriteLine("1: Add a game");
        Console.WriteLine("2: Remove a game");
        Console.WriteLine("3: List games");
        Console.WriteLine("4: Save games");
        Console.WriteLine("5: Read games from file");
        Console.WriteLine("6: Quit");
        Console.Write("Enter the number of your choice: ");
        userChoice = Console.ReadLine();

        if(!Int32.TryParse(userChoice, out num)) continue;

        if (userChoice == "6")
        {
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Choice = " + userChoice);

        if(userChoice == "1")
        {
            //Some code that will allow me to enter info on some game
        // it will then display the menu again after all questions are answered.
        }

    } while (true);
```

Answer (score 2):

Put the if checks inside the do while loop. You are checking them outside the loop and hence nothing gets processed. Either put them inside the do while loop or put them inside a function and call the function after you take input from the user.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove `!` from the while condition and also need some way of breaking that loop if user inputs 6 look at below code snippet:

```
    int num = 0;
    string userChoice = string.Empty;
    do
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Select the number of your choice: ");
        Console.WriteLine("1: Add a game");
        Console.WriteLine("2: Remove a game");
        Console.WriteLine("3: List games");
        Console.WriteLine("4: Save games");
        Console.WriteLine("5: Read games from file");
        Console.WriteLine("6: Quit");
        Console.Write("Enter the number of your choice: ");
        if(num == 6)
            break;
        else
            userChoice = Console.ReadLine();

    }
    while (Int32.TryParse(userChoice, out num)); //checks to see if the input is a number
    if (userChoice == "6")
    {
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }
```

Full code is [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5oDaZM).

Answer (score 0):

```
int num;
 string userChoice;
 do
 {
     Console.WriteLine("Select the number of your choice: ");
     Console.WriteLine("1: Add a game");
     Console.WriteLine("2: Remove a game");
     Console.WriteLine("3: List games");
     Console.WriteLine("4: Save games");
     Console.WriteLine("5: Read games from file");
     Console.WriteLine("6: Quit");
     Console.Write("Enter the number of your choice: ");
     userChoice = Console.ReadLine();
 } while (Int32.Parse(userChoice) != 6);
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove '!' from `while (!Int32.TryParse(userChoice, out num));` [Read Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx).